# Delete pop up by id,div,class

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I have created free hosting site and it keeps popping up an ad of the site on load. What I want is to delete the specific rows that include the ad. I want to delete the ****BOLD**** rows as they are the same every time.

```
<head></head>
<body class="twoColFixRtHdr">
    <map name="map1"></map>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div id="container"></div>
    **<div class="bModal __bPopup1" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); height: 100%; left: 0px; opa…ixed; top: 0px; width: 100%; z-index: 9998; cursor: pointer;"></div>
    <div id="visas_style_div" class="popup" style="left: 627px; position: absolute; top: 20px; z-index: 9999;"></div>**
</body>
```

Comment: I don't advice to do something like this. Because they are giving you a free service and they need to earn money.

Comment: Anyway i would like to delete the pop up and place an add inside the site at the left column..its not useful for my job..can you help? for educational reasons if you still don't advise that.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use document.getElementsByClassName:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hidepopup() {
    var divpopup = document.getElementsByClassName('bModal __bPopup1');
    if(divpopup.length > 0)
        divpopup[0].style.display = 'none';
}
window.onload = hidepopup;
</script>
```